# Registering and getting an environment in Azure Machine Learning Studio that derives from a self-created Docker image

Tags: azure, environment, azure-machine-learning-service, docker-image

I need to register an environment in Azure Machine Learning Studio which derives from a self-created Docker image. I have found this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-custom-image#use-a-private-container-registry-optional) by Microsoft that describes the process of using a custom Docker image as an environment.

Unfortunately, the documentation does not explain how to register the resulting environment into the workspace in order to get the environment when needed.

Normally, you describe and register an environment like this:

```
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies

# Create a Python environment for the experiment
diabetes_env = Environment("diabetes-experiment-env")
diabetes_env.python.user_managed_dependencies = False # Let Azure ML manage dependencies
diabetes_env.docker.enabled = True # Use a docker container

# Create a set of package dependencies (conda or pip as required)
diabetes_packages = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=['scikit-learn','ipykernel','matplotlib','pandas','pip'],
                                             pip_packages=['azureml-sdk','pyarrow'])

# Add the dependencies to the environment
diabetes_env.python.conda_dependencies = diabetes_packages

# Register the environment
diabetes_env.register(workspace=ws)
```

Then, when you need the defined environment, you can get it with:

```
# get the registered environment
registered_env = Environment.get(ws, 'diabetes-experiment-env')
```

[Source](https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/DP100/blob/master/05A%20-%20Working%20with%20Environments.ipynb)

As it seems to me, this approach does not work for environments that derive from self-created Docker images.

For example, I define and register an environment like this:

```
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core import ContainerRegistry

registry = ContainerRegistry()
registry.address = "name_of_container_registry.azurecr.io"
registry.username = "username"
registry.password = "password"
myenv = Environment.from_docker_image('env_name', 'name_of_container_registry.azurecr.io/docker_image_name:latest', container_registry=registry, conda_specification=None, pip_requirements=None)
myenv.register(workspace=ws)
```

Then, in the script where I need to have the above-defined environment:

```
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
from azureml.core.webservice import LocalWebservice

model = Model(ws, 'exemplarily_model')

registered_env = Environment.get(ws, 'env_name')

inference_config = InferenceConfig(environment=registered_env, 
                                   source_directory='./source_dir', 
                                   entry_script='./score.py') 

deployment_config = LocalWebservice.deploy_configuration(port=6789)

service = Model.deploy(
    ws,
    "myservice",
    [model],
    inference_config,
    deployment_config,
    overwrite=True,
)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
print(service.get_logs())
```

Everytime the inference service deployment fails with the exception "Authentication failed for container registry name_of_container_registry.azurecr.io". However, when I change `environment=registered_env` to `environment=myenv`, the inference service starts successfully without any error.

This brings me to the conclusion that registering and getting an environment in Azure Machine Learning Studio that derives from a self-created Docker image works differently. 

Therefore, I would like to ask for the correct commands for registering and getting an environment in Azure Machine Learning Studio that derives from a self-created Docker image.

**Update:** 
I found a possibility to get the environments that derives from a self-created Docker image:

Instead of registering the environment with the command `myenv.register(workspace=ws)`, you can save the environment to a directory with the command `myenv.save_to_directory(path="./env", overwrite=True)`.
Then you can load the environment in a different script with `newenv = Environment.load_from_directory(path="./env")`.
This approach works for me to deploy my inference service.
I found the possibility for getting a saved environment here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments#use-existing-environments)

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel, register() returns a registered instance of environment. If environment was previously registered the corresponding version will be returned, otherwise AzureML service will create a new version and return back to the client.
Now, when you do Environment.get() with **no** version specified, it returns you latest registered, that might be different that you would expect playing a lot with your environment.
So, can you please just see **repr** of the environment returned by register() and by get(). or simply check env.register(ws).version and Environment.get(ws, name).version. I believe that will shed the light on the mystery.
Please do not rely on the latest version, but specify the exact version or label, latter is more flexible and preferred

Answer (score 0):

can you please confirm that environment returned by register() is the same you retrieve as latest (with no version specified) Environment.get()?

Comment: `myenv = Environment.from_docker_image('env_name', 'name_of_container_registry.azurecr.io/docker_image_name:latest', container_registry=registry, conda_specification=None, pip_requirements=None)
myenv.register(workspace=ws)` and `registered_env = Environment.get(ws, 'env_name')`  use as environment name the same string, here 'env_name'.

Comment: Therefore, I think that it is the same environment. Moreover, there is no error thrown when the command `registered_env = Environment.get(ws, 'env_name')` is executed.

Comment: I have just used the command ´registered_env.save_to_directory(path="./env", overwrite=True)` for the the saved and the loaded environment, and took a look into the json-files. There is a difference between the saved and the loaded environment! Under "docker" -> "baseImageRegistry" the password is not set for the loaded environment, but for the saved environment. This is probably the reason why authentication failed!

Comment: Hi Daniel, why is it needed to save the Environment to a directory?... when the registered environment is already available in the AML workspace...just curious...could you please shed some light on it?

Comment: Hi Priya, it is not needed to save the environment to a directory. However, I need to save/register the environment anyhow. Unfortunately, saving/registering and getting an environment that derives from a self-created Docker image does not work on my side. Therefore, I found the workaround with saving the environment to a directory. It is not ideal, but how else should I do it?

Comment: I have used `environment.yml` file to create the required environment and registered in the AML workspace for Azure-ML pipeline to work. I am creating a `runconfig` object and attaching environment to that and passing it as a parameter to the pipeline steps. I have not used a custom dockerfile to create environment so didn't encounter any error, was just curious to know...